# OFFSET | FETCH Order By column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, fetch, offset

Can anyone explain to me on a very basic level what the performance difference would be for these 2 queries.

```
ORDER BY (select null)
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @EntriesPerPage ROWS ONLY;

ORDER BY (ItemID)
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @EntriesPerPage ROWS ONLY;
```

I would expect the first query to perform better because it is not ordering by a column but every time i test this the second query always performs better. Can anyone explain to me why the second query would run better for OFFSET / FETCH even though it is ordering by a column.

I run the queries separately. I wipe the cache plan and buffers between each query so that it doesn't use the previous execution plan.

Thanks

Comment: Is ItemID indexed?

Comment: How exactly are you testing?

Comment: Cold/hot data? (Run each query twice.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first query should run faster as the second query need to do an additional sorting operation.

Answer (score 0):

First query should be faster .

Did you try executing second query first and see the difference in performance. Might be indexing and other performance attributes makes you feel second query executes faster.